# Windows Phone Emulator Not Running on Visual Studio 2015 (Windows 10 pro)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emulation, hyper-v

I am trying to run a Windows Phone Emulator, running Visual Studio 2015 Professional, on Windows 10 pro (64 bit), Here's the error I get when I run the emulator in VS:

It gets stuck on "Loading OS.." and I get this after a few seconds:

[image]

When I try running the emulator in the Hyper-V Manager, I get this error:

[image]

I have already turned on Virtualization in my BIOS & Checked the "Hyper-V" option in programs and features.

My machine:

Intel Core i7 3770K (4 Physical Cores, 8 Threads) & 32GB of RAM.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The message in the dialog is too small to read. It would be nice to you type the message directly in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to but it was way too long, you can simply right-click and open in a new window, that shows its  original size, thanks in advance.

Comment: @DarkInferno - it actually does not. no option to open an image in the new window....

Comment: Alright, sorry about that guys, I've re-uploaded the screenshots, should be readable now.

Comment: Instead of screen shots, do <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> and copy the text of the message and paste that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Intel Core i7 3770K](http://ark.intel.com/products/65523/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) does not support one of the virtualization components, the `VT-d` (virtualization with Directed I/O). This is where the virtual manager can assign hardware to a VM (i.e. such as NIC port).

You will need to run this on other hardware.

---

Here are the scenarios, *#1 I experienced directly after installing a non-related Azure update*:

1. Something installed may have affected the original install of Visual Studio. Re-run the install of Visual Studio, or the latest update, and select `Repair` to fix the issue.
2. Try creating a virtual running a generic OS in the machine's Hyper-V. If it cannot start it could be one of the following issues:

   1. The OS can't run Hyper-V either because it is a consumer version which doesn't have Hyper-V capabilities.
   2. The computer's BIOS doesn't have virtualization capabilities or it is turned off in BIOS. Check BIOS to turn on.
   3. The processor doesn't run all components of virtualization and even though the BIOS does, the Hyper-V manager fails.

Comment: Tried it, it did not fix the problem :(

Comment: @DarkInferno Can you create and run a hyper-v virtual? If you can there, then the problem is VS, if not there its the hyper-v of your OS.

Comment: I tried running the windows phone emulators created by VS through the Hyper-V manager and whenever I try to "Start" any of those, it throws the error I posted in the screen shot, I tried setting the number of virtual processors to "1" in their configuration but that didn't help either, this is really getting on my nerves...

Comment: @DarkInferno, Upon looking up the chip on Intels web site, it does not have a critical virtualization feature of VT-d which the emulation/virtualization needs. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Omega, correct me if I'm wrong but I believe Hyper-V requires only the VT-x virtualization feature to run & the 3770K supports that, also upon some research I found out that you actually need to disable VT-d via BIOS to be able to make it work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx